# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Insider Preview

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

My laptop currently has Windows 8.1 installed, and I'm about to update to Windows 10. However, before I do that, I'd like to install the Insider Preview on it, so that I can keep up with what's coming.

I am already an Insider, I used to have the preview installed on a separate machine, so the install is no problem to me, but I can't seem to find where to download the ISO now (I stupidly deleted the one I used before).

Has Microsoft closed the Preview? Or what? Or where can I download the ISO? insiders.windows.com doesn't give it to me.

Comment: The only way to be an Insider as of July 29th 2015 is if you have a legitimate retail installation of Windows 10 installed or you kept your already installed Insider Preview installation current.  Since you currently don't have a preview build before 10240 installed, your only choice, would be to install Windows 10 twice on the same machine.  You can do this easily enough, one installation will simply be opted into the preview, the other will not be.

Comment: @Ramhound - what about Product Keys? I have a Windows 8 one (I think)

Comment: What about it?  When you upgrade to Windows 10 from a previous installation of Windows a generic key is issued, the same generic key for everyone, in my example of having two installations they would activate automatically.  When asked for a product key you simply skip that step, as indicated in the half dozen answers, to the half dozen near duplicates on this site.